# Failed to construct interpreter TensorflowLite

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using `

> Cuda 10.1, cudnn 7.6, Tensorflow 2.3.0, keras 2.4.3

When training model I use `save_weights_only=True`, and a folder is saved including:

> assets, variables and saved_model.pb

When i am converting the model to a tflite model using:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('x/210126_Test')
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

I get no errors of any kind, though when i am trying to use the model in an iPad appliacation, it only returns following:

> "Exception Error: Failed to construct interpreter"

Have anyone experienced this or know a possible solution?

.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved through changes of packages versions.

> Tensorflow = 2.0.0 & Keras = 2.3.1